How should I handle comments posted as answers to off-topic questions?
Numerous times I've run across an off-topic question that someone has posted comments on that attempt to answer the question. I understand the desire to help people but such comments should not be posted. It only encourages off-topic questions.
I downvote the question since it is off-topic and I vote to close it as not being a programming question (or vote to have it migrated if appropriate).
But my question here is: How can I handle the comments that attempt to answer the off-topic question? I'm tempted to just flag the comments as "No longer needed" but I thought I would solicit thoughts here first.
I've seen one very high-rep user post such comments many times. Is there an appropriate way to get them to stop?
Related (but not a duplicate): Should one advise on off-topic questions?

NOTES:
By off-topic question, I'm referring to questions that clearly do not belong of SO, but instead belong on another SE site. I am not referring to questions would be fine on SO if they just provided a few more relevant details.
And the types of comments I'm referring to are comments that actually answer the off-topic question. I am not referring to comments that explain to the OP why their question is off-topic or explain a better SE site to post the question.
Lastly, the high-rep user I mentioned was the first to VTC as "not a programming question". Despite this, that user still likes to "answer" the question in one or more comments to the off-topic question.

I'd first ping the user who posted such a comment suggesting they read that Meta post. While the consensus is that it's not a good idea to advise off-topic questions, it's not exactly a rule, so I think trying to get mods to forcibly get the user to stop would be a mistake. There've been a number of times I've found useful information in a comment on a closed off-topic question while trying to figure something out, even though that admittedly isn't the intent of SO.

I don't think there needs to be a zero-tolerance policy here. I don't see a problem with providing some guidance in comments in addition to voting to close. (E.g. if a user asks a debugging question without a MCVE, do you say I shouldn't give them debugging advice in comments? That would be answering an off-topic question after all. Or if a kid asks for career/life advice, why not give some minimal advice? I don't think either of those motivates them to come back with more bad questions.)

I tend to do a double whammy. I explain what went wrong and I also do the good Samaritan thing by kicking people in the right direction. The site has so many rules it is nearly impossible to actually help anyone, let people have their moment in the comments. Yes it is comment abuse and yes it sets a wrong precedent, but the site is already inhuman enough as it is.

I am not sure if much can be done about this. Comments cannot be downvoted and we can only delete them by flagging. There's no option to flag comments as "encouraging unwanted behavior". Even if we had such option, I don't think it would be effective as once the comment is posted, then the unwanted behavior of asking low quality questions is encouraged.
Putting comments aside, we still have an issue with users avoiding using their privileges such as casting close votes. Everyday I see duplicate or low quality questions getting duplicated or elaborated suggestions in form of answers. We can at least downvote those, close the questions, and cast delete votes. But beyond that, I have not seen any effective penalties (at least not often as there are no definitive rules against such behaviors).
So, to answer your question; I guess we are stuck to witness those comments.

"we still have an issue with users avoiding using their privileges such as casting close votes." I tried to help.

@KarlKnechtel that was/is a great post. If I could, I'd upvote it again.


How to handle comments posted as answers to off-topic questions?

If the comment provides guidance to the user about why the question is not appropriate or even hints and answers to such questions, then don't flag such comments as NLN flag will most likely be declined.
When the question is closed, then some guidance comments about why the question is off-topic can be flagged as NLN, but there is no need to do that either. Cleaning up NLN comments of all kinds on questions that don't belong here is mere exercise in futility.
Such questions will be collected by roomba, and if they don't satisfy conditions for automatic deletion, you can always go to SO Close Vote Reviewers chat room and post a del-pls request so community can clean up. There is no need to involve moderators.
If the question is off-topic and you are worried that it will not get closed, you can also go to SOCVR and ask for help to close.
That does not mean that moderator will not act and do some additional actions when they come across such question, but they also might not. I am not saying that you shouldn't flag comments on off-topic questions as NLN, just that there are other ways to deal with such content.
There is no harm in offering advice or help in comments regardless of the question topicality. If user posts more of such questions they will most likely get question banned sooner or later.
As for noticing that there is a comment from user that could have acted by casting close or down vote on such question and there are none, there is again no need to do anything or judge such user. First of all they are not obliged to do anything and there could be many reasons why they didn't act. For instance, they might have run out of close votes or downvotes so all they could do was to comment.

My experience is that NLN comment flags have a quite high success rate. However, I agree it's unnecessary work for at least two people, if the question will be roomba'd anyway.

@KarlKnechtel Yes, they do have high success rate. But, I would definitely decline it on an comment which provides an answer, unless the answer has already been posted or there is a link to some other Q/A which covers what answer says. There is no point in removing pieces of useful information just because question is off topic. That the whole question may be deleted at some point is another unrelated thing.

To be clear, I specifically stated "comments that attempt to answer the question". By that, I mean actual answers. I am not referring to helpful comments that explain how the question is off-topic and where best to ask the question. This is about comments that would actually be posted as answers if the question was on-topic.

I can edit my answer to specifically talk only about comments that answer the question, but my answer wouldn't be much different. Except that I would probably more explicitly say that flags on answers in comments is more likely to be declined. It is far better that someone posts answer in comment than full answer. And thinking that such comments would prevent people from posting off topic questions (that missed the site) is just wishful thinking. People who intentionally post such off topic questions here are very rare. Most of them posts because they don't know other sites exist.
